# How do I add a second responsive menu in WordPress/WooCommerce?

Tags: wordpress, responsive-design, woocommerce

I am working on a WordPress shop. I am using the WooCommerce plugin.

I need to add a second responsive menu. The problem is, that menu items will change depending on the page. For example, the menu needs to be different for the 'shop' page and the 'about' page.

Without WooCommerce (in pure WordPress), I would simply use different header templates for each page (by using page templates). In WooCommerce it seems to work differently.

I don't want to use plugins. How can I do it?

Comment: You can follow the same concept for woocommerce pages as well. It will work. e.g. different header file for 'shop' page, different header file 'about' page etc.

Comment: **The easiest solution:** You can also keep one menu and you add classes on the menu items that change. After that, on your CSS file you `display` or **hide** this items depending on which type of page or which page ID, you are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have access to the source, you can use conditionals in PHP.

For example:

```
if(is_page(('shop')) : 
    ('your_shop_menu'); // consider fix this php, it's example only (you can use is_shop() when is Woocommerce Home Shop)
elseif(is_page(('about')) : // You can use page's slug
    ('your_about_menu'); // consider fix this php, it's example only
else : 
    ('your_default_menu'); // or empty if you don't need menu
endif;
```

Please see

https://docs.woothemes.com/document/conditional-tags/
https://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags

Edit: You can manage differents menus via WP Admin

- Menu for Shop Page
- Menu for About Page